# wubi said files is missing after selecting UEFI and csm

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, uefi, samsung

After installing ubuntu using wubi and selecting `UEFI` and csm UEFI as disabled in samsung series 5 with window 8,  wubi said files is missing.

Do i need to install with wubi again?

i read the answer, it said to use livecd, but i only hope not actual install in partition, only expect wubi in windows 8, after read, it is quite terrible to install partition with livecd , it said choose anything you want during installation, but i already installed in window 8 already. Why install again using livecd. finally it said it may not boot window 8 any more. is it possible to keep using window 8 boot manager to boot ubuntu?

Comment: i read the answer, it said to use livecd, but i only hope not actual install in partition, only expect wubi in windows 8, after read, it is quite terrible to install partition with livecd , it said choose anything you want during installation, but i already installed in window 8 already. Why install again using livecd. finally it said it may not boot window 8 any more. is it possible to keep using window 8 boot manager to boot ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just switch from UEFI to CSM and expect it to boot. That will just stop Windows booting. Wubi doesn't work on UEFI **period**.

Wubi doesn't work on UEFI computers due to the partition table the disk uses. The only way to get it to work would be to completely reformat, reinstall Windows and then install Wubi.

Even then, replacing a GPT disk with MBR partition table doesn't clean up all GPT data and Ubuntu will fail to install due to exceptions thrown from `parted`. You'd have to download a program called [`fixparts`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) to completely erase the GPT data.

This is obviously an excessive amount of effort to go to in order to install Wubi which is generally intended to try out Ubuntu safely.

Since Wubi does not support **any** new computers shipping with Windows 8, or *any* computer booting via `UEFI` you have to choose an alternative method of which there are many:

1. normal dual boot
2. replace Windows
3. install (non Wubi) to an external drive
4. install in a virtual machine
5. run from a live USB with persistence
6. run from a live DVD

Comment: if i run from a live DVD, and write a c network program, where do the program saved ? do it have enough tools to compile c program in live DVD?

Comment: Unless you mount a hard drive partition and save it there, it will save it to the live file system which is lost after shutdown. If instead you used a live USB with persistence, it would save it. Yes you should be able to compile a C program.